# Can I point ItemNotFoundUrl at sitecore content?

Tags: configuration

In my attempt to customize error pages, I have overridden the settings for ItemNotFoundUrl, LinkItemNotFoundUrl, and LayoutNotFoundUrl to point to a page in sitecore; /errors/ContentNotFound.  The page exists and renders when I navigate to it, but when I try to trigger it with a bad path I get this instead:
[image: Server Error in Application]

When I use a static page for the setting, I get its content.  Can I not use a Sitecore hosted page as the target for these *NotFound conditions?